# How is a radio button unchecked, if there's only one button?

Tags: html, checkbox, radio-button

I have these two radio buttons inside an Input Form:

```
<input type="radio" name="info_only_on" value="yes"> Info-only  
<input type="radio" name="info_only_on" value="off"> (Clear Button)
```

It creates two buttons, so the user can check info-only and then turn off info-only if they made a mistake.  I created the 2nd button because once the radio button is checked, clicking it again, doesn't deselect it.

I've switched to type="checkbox", which does let the user deselect.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="info_only_on" value="yes">
```

Looking at specs for the radio type button, I'm not seeing anything for the user unchecking it.  What am I missing?

I'm using html, php and avoiding javascript.

---

The php used to check the box value is:

```
 // When info_only_on is set to clear, it's value should be passed here as "no" 
if($_POST["info_only_on"] == "yes")                                     
{ $info_only =  "Added Member info online but not paying online. ";   }
else 
{ $info_only = " ";  }   

  // BUILD UP MESSAGE to email to our membership chair  
$MsgToWrite = "\r\n" . $BasicInfo . $PhoneInfo . $EmailInfo;
If ($info_only <> " ") 
{   $MsgToWrite = $MsgToWrite . "\r\n" . $info_only; }
```

Comment: why are you avoiding javascript? this is something perfectly suited for javascript, however can be achieved by using pure css and toggling opacity... post the full source code so I can see.

Comment: So what is the issue in using checkbox?

Comment: @divy - checkbox is fine here, but I want to solve this mystery for when I want to use radio boxes.  Even if there's a few radio boxes, I'd like the option of selecting none of them.

Comment: @curls OK, but it isn't possible using just CSS, you need JavaScript/JQuery, for sure. Also i would say if you get along using JavaScript then avoid radio buttons for this to happen, find other alternative.  I can help you with that(JavaScript Solution).

Comment: @Jordan - given my users who several who have javascript turned off, I'd like to avoid it.  This is the full source code.  The only other line is the input form with action (etc.) and various html text to the screen and input text elements.  It's older code a little refashioned, so it's laid out with tables and doesn't have a .css id associated with it.  (I use .css elsewhere, so could easily add an .css element if it would help.)  What's the opacity feature?

Comment: @divy - considering I'm pretty rusty on javascript and know what I'm trying to solve here - i'd be interesting to see your javascript solution (so I can learn.)

Comment: @curls yea whats wrong with using checkbox?

Comment: @Jordan - I answered this already :) (see above).  I'm editing the qusetion to add the php code that checks the box.  That's what you were asking for!  I didn't realize it.

Comment: @curls okay coo coo, let me know if you need help with anything else.

Comment: @Jordan - you mentioned being able to do it with .css and opacity.  Can you explain more?

Comment: Its possible though CSS animations... using the `play-state` property and toggling but honestly not worth all the work to implement something like that when you have checkboxes that do this exact feature lol.

Comment: I also want to have this cause (1) I am trying to not use JS (2) I am trying to make a collapsible content using CSS only. So if anyone else has an answer, it would be appreciated...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that you can do it without javascript, here is a simple example :

HTML Code :

```
<input type="radio" name="name" id="radioBtn" onclick="test(this)" /> Radio
```

Javascript Code :

```
    var radioState = false;
    function test(element){
        if(radioState == false) {
            check();
            radioState = true;
        }else{
            uncheck();
            radioState = false;
        }
    }
    function check() {
        document.getElementById("radioBtn").checked = true;
    }
    function uncheck() {
        document.getElementById("radioBtn").checked = false;
    }
```

Take a look here : https://jsfiddle.net/eloufirhatim/ypwhugxz/

Comment: Thanks!  I'm a little lost looking at it.  But have to go do stuff, so I'm going to come back this evening and stare some more.  I don't see where element is set to pass to function test.  Nor why why check() isn't the test clause in the if statement.  I'm completely lost -- need to look when I have time.

Comment: When you click in the radio button (onclick attribute) the TEST function is launched, this function test a variable named "radioState" (initialized at false) : radioState = true -> the radio button is checked and false means radio button unchecked, so if the variable tested is false the function CHECK is launched to check the radio button, else the function UNCHECK is launched that uncheck the radio button

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense now.  I still dont' understand how test(this) gets a 'this', or whether the element in test(element) can be any name or needs to be element so that getElementById gets the onclick value.  Can the process be also be done as I edited above?

Comment: the parameter "this" is to pass the input radio as a parameter to the function, so you can use it in the function, but it's optionnal here 'coz I don't use it in the function so you can use the function like : test()

Comment: So element is a choice and has nothing to do with element in the document.getElementById("radioBtn").checked phrase?

Comment: Yes element is optionnal and the document.getElementById is to get the element by his id (the html attribute "id=") you are welcom ;)

Comment: Note that according to spec, a radio button cannot be single `A tree must not contain an input element whose radio button group contains only that element.` https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#radio-button-state-(type=radio)

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there is no way to deselect a single radio button using HTML. In HTML, exactly one radio button needs to be selected. If you want the ability to deselect all radio buttons after one was selected, then you will have to use javascript for this.

From Wikipedia: "It is possible that initially none of the radio buttons in a group are selected. This unselected state cannot be restored by interacting with the radio button widget, though it may be possible through other user interface elements." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_button

Comment: @BC - well that's a silly design.  But it does explain why I couldn't spot a way to do exactly the opposite of that (and get it deselected.)  Seems odd that checkboxes can be, but radio buttons can't be.  The interpreter (browsers') code should be able to be standardized so both can work.  Thanks for the information!

Comment: @BC - I posted with your name written out and @ and it disappeared.  Then posted wtih at-BC and it stayed.  I've seen this happen before.  Is it something simple I'm not doing, or do I need to ask in meta to figure this out?